# onload function only displays one result (I think the last item in the list) x number of times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filereader

I'm trying to add a link to each item in the list that I obtained using `fileList.push({name:name});`. [image]

My problem is when I try to add the add the link in the onload function using `fileList.push({link:href});` it ends up only grabbing the result only from one file (I believe the last file).

[image]

Here's my code:

```
class Download extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

    this.inputRef = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      files: []
    };
  }

  handleClick = event => {

     const self = this;

     let file, name, href;

     let breh = event.target;

     const fileList = [];




      for (let x = 0, xlen = breh.files.length; x < xlen; x++) {


        file = breh.files[x];
        name = file.name;

        fileList.push({name:name});
        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = e => {
        href = e.target.result;
        fileList.push({link:href});
    };








        reader.readAsDataURL(file)

      }

      self.setState({ files: fileList });
  };

  render() {
     console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="input">
        <input
          onChange={this.handleClick}
          id="upload-file"
          className="inputName"
          type="file"
          multiple
          ref={this.inputRef}
        />
        <div>
          <ul ref={this.ulRef}>
            {this.state.files.map((file, index) => (
              <li key={index}>
                <Link to={file.link}>{file.name}</Link>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Download;
```

Comment: You keep using the same variables. Move `let file, name, href;` inside the loop along with `reader.readAsDataURL(file)`

Comment: Other issue is you are setting the state before the asynchronous calls are done.

Comment: How would I set it after if I could?

Comment: When I add setState in my onload function it just prints out an array for each item displaying the same info. https://imgur.com/a/7wuukx0

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple issues in your code. The main issue is you are using the file reader outside the loop so it is only going to be the last file. Other issue is where varaiables are declared and how you are setting the state.

You want to use promises (or await)

Solution using promises would look like:

```js
// Made it a function so it is runnable here in a snipplet without react.
// contents of this will work fine in your react component
handleClick = event => {

  // Helper code to read file and return promise
  const readFile = (file) => {

    const fileReader = new FileReader()

    // create the promise and return it
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      // if file reader has an error, report it
      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject({ error })
      }

      // if success, resolve the promise
      fileReader.onload = () => {
        resolve({
          name: file.name,
          link: fileReader.result
        })
      }
  
      // start reading the file
      fileReader.readAsText(file);
    })
  }

  // create all the file reader promises
  // create an array from the files list and use map to generate
  // an array of promises
  const allReaders = Array.from(event.target.files).map(readFile)
  
  // Now handle the array of promises we just created
  Promise.all(allReaders)
    .then(fileList => {
      console.log(fileList)
      // set the state that we have all the files
      //this.setState({ files: fileList });
    })
    .catch(error => { 
       console.error(error)
    });

}

// just for runnable example without react
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change", handleClick)
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple/>
```

Comment: I don't know where else to put this code. This is not a working file but is this the right code for my js file? https://codepen.io/Dillon1025/pen/KKwNyzz. If so here is the result I'm getting, even though it still displays correctly for the list items: https://imgur.com/a/K3sKXSP

Comment: Copy the contents out of the `handleClick` function above and stick it in your handleClick method....

Comment: Hey I think it's giving me a different link every time which is good but the functionality is slow and when I click a link (which I turned into a hrefs) it brings me to a blank page and shows me about:blank#blocked in the address bar.

Comment: Going to be slow because it is asynchronous calls. You can update the state with each promise, but it will grow slowly Persoanally I would add a loading icon until they are loaded.

Comment: Okay I guess it's fine for now. Do you know why it brings me to a blank page with "about:blank#blocked" in the address bar. I'm wanting it to bring up and play the audio.

Comment: My problem was I was using `readAsText()` instead of `readAsDataURL()` but it's still displaying the same link now.